# MS Access: double loop query with multiple conditions to display on Form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-forms

Let's try to phrase this properly, here is a summary of my relevant tables:

1. Table "students" containing student_id, first_name, last_name.
2. Table "courses" containing course_id, title.
3. Table "majors" containing major_id, major_name.

Students are assigned to majors, and courses are assigned to majors (i.e. courses required to obtain the specific major), as a result, I have the two following tables defining which students and courses are assigned to which majors.

4. Table "students_assigned_majors" containing ref_id (PK), student_id (FK), major_id (FK).
5. Table "courses_assigned_majors" containing ref_id (PK), course_id (FK), major_id (FK).

Finally, I have this table called
6. "completed_courses" containing information on which students completed which courses, with columns ref_id (PK), student_id (FK), course_id (FK), completion_date.

I want to create a query that checks which students are not eligible to graduate from the major because they are missing a course required by the major. Any course is not valid if it was completed more than 5 years ago.

I want to display these students and their majors on an existing Form.

I am unsure if this can be done entirely in MS Access SQL... I drafted a VBA procedure on the On_current event of the relevant form, and for now it looks like this: (still Pseudo-code not tested, but here is the idea)

```
Private Sub Form_Current(major_parameter as String)
    Dim Sql_cour As String
    Dim Sql_stud As String
    
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs_courses As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs_students As DAO.Recordset
    
    Set Sql_cour = "SELECT course_id FROM courses_assigned_major WHERE major_id = {major_parameter};"
                
    Set Sql_stud = "SELECT student_id, first_name, last_name FROM students_assigned_majors as SAM  LEFT OUTER JOIN students as S on (SAM.student_id = S.student_id) WHERE SAM.major_id = {major_parameter};"

    Set rs_courses = db.OpenRecordset(Sql_cour)
    Set rs_students = db.OpenRecordset(Sql_stud)
    
    Do While Not rs_students.EOF
        Do While Not rs_courses.EOF
            'check completed_courses table for student_id, course_id, date of course < 5 years ago

            'If conditions not met
                'Add student to new query/table "not_eligible"
                Exit inner Loop
            rs_courses.MoveNext
        Loop
        rs_students.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

I am looking for general advice on the best way to accomplish this, and if from your experience, this drafted solution is worth investing time to complete, or if I am completely off track.

More specifically, if this is the way to go, some further uncertainties are:

1. Where do I store this subroutine? Is it OK to store it in the current event of the form?
2. Where do I store the values of the students that do not comply with the requirements? which I later want to display on the form?

Thank you for any help, hope to provide an interesting challenge.
Regards

Comment: 1. Have you tried this code? It makes no sense to build Current event procedure with an argument and it will just error anyway. Put the code in its own procedure in a general module. Probably needs to be a function that returns a True/False value called from a query. 2. Normally, you don't. Build a query and display its results in a form or listbox. Alternative is to save data to a 'temp' table.

Comment: Really should provide sample data and desired output as text tables. Advise not to use exact same field names in multiple tables. Consider something like: student_id_fk_CC, student_id_fk_CAM, student_id_fk_SAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this query to find students that have not completed courses required by associated major:

```
SELECT stud_maj_courses.student_id, stud_maj_courses.major_id_fk_SAM, stud_maj_courses.course_id_fk_CAM
FROM (
     (SELECT students.student_id, students_assigned_majors.major_id_fk_SAM, courses_assigned_majors.course_id_fk_CAM
      FROM (students INNER JOIN students_assigned_majors ON students.student_id = students_assigned_majors.student_id_fk_SAM) 
      INNER JOIN courses_assigned_majors ON students_assigned_majors.major_id_fk_SAM = courses_assigned_majors.major_id_fk_CAM) 
   AS stud_maj_courses 
INNER JOIN students ON stud_maj_courses.student_id = students.student_id) 
LEFT JOIN completed_courses ON (stud_maj_courses.course_id_fk_CAM = completed_courses.course_id_fk_CC) 
AND (stud_maj_courses.student_id = completed_courses.student_id_fk_CC)
WHERE (((completed_courses.student_id_fk_CC) Is Null)) OR (((completed_courses.completion_date)<#5/31/2016#));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support! Cleaner solution for sure, will step up mi SQL skills :)  just for others, spotted an error on line 4, it should be  "ON students.student_id = students_assigned_majors.student_id_fk_SAM)". Cheers

Comment: Ooops, don't know how that happened. Edited answer.